# How do I use minecraft mods?

Tags: minecraft

How do I add the mod to my game (minecraft 1.8) ?
I'v got it on my desktop but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Which modification?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to http://minecraftforge.net, scroll down and find "1.8 latest" and choose installer to download.
2. Download the .jar file then go to properties of the file then mark "allow executing file as program and open with "Open jdk 7 runtime" have an active INTERNET connection then install the client.
3. Navigate to your `.minecraft` folder and create a `mods` folder.
4. Open your minecraft launcher; a profile `Forge` should pop up - select it.
5. Select "1.8 Forge" (scroll down).
6. Paste any mod that is in .jar format into the `mods` folder. (go to http://9minecraft.net to get these mods)

Some mods will not work so if minecraft crashes just delete it. It may be a good idea to take and backup your worlds on your desktop by going to `.minecraft/saves` and copy all of your folder worlds.

Comment: 9minecraft is terrible go to https://curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods as it's better in every way