# I want to install Minecraft Forge on Ubuntu 18

Tags: java, minecraft

I tried to follow the instructions to an [an older version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592767/how-do-i-use-minecraft-mods/592853#592853?newreg=d5ffc18d61244f26b48fcbb9df6913d5) of the operating system, the .jar file will not open after I allowed it to be executed as a program. There isn't any kind of pop-up anywhere the .jar simply will not open.